# Magento 2.3 place the order button below payment methods

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3, place-order

I want to move the place order button in my Magento 2.3 checkout, from inside the payment method itself, to below all payment methods.

So when selecting the payment method, it should be clicked on a place order button below all payment methods.